# Increment substring numbers by +1

Tags: python

I have a Python script running on AWS Lambda (serverless). When triggered it needs to add a new row to a Google Spreadsheet via the API and that involves copying some of the formulas from the row above to the new row. But for the formulas to be valid the cell row numbers need to be incremented by +1 before copying to the new row.

Example say I have a cell with formula `=if(countif(G198:G201,"<=3")<=3,0,1)`. I need to change this to `=if(countif(G199:G202,"<=3")<=3,0,1)` and add to the new row.

Whats the easiest way to identify the numbers that identify cells in the formula and increment them to create the new formula?

Comment: You should look into regexes.

Answer (score 0):

```
def update_formula(formula):
    import re
    cells = re.findall('[A-Z][0-9]+',formula)
    for cell in cells:
      row_number = re.search('[0-9]+',cell).group(0)
      new_row_number = int(row_number) + 1
      new_cell = cell.replace(str(row_number),str(new_row_number))
      formula = formula.replace(cell,new_cell)

    return formula
```